# Get variables datatypes in kernel mode drivers windows

Tags: c++, c, kernel, driver, windows-kernel

I want to know if there is any method in kernel mode drivers which gives the datatype of a variable. Like if I declare:

```
INT i = 0;
```

And ask about datatype of "i", it will return INT. I also want the same thing for structures.

Comment: Data types are known at compile time.  Why would you want to do this at run time?

Comment: I am taking all parameters in API as pointer, and want to decide where call should go on parameters type base in kernel.

Comment: So the function in question accepts parameters of type `void *`?  Then you need to pass in additional information somehow on the type.

Comment: yes exactly i need it in same way.

Comment: One way would be to pass in an enum value which represents the type, then have a `switch` in the function to handle the type based on that.

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of what you're attempting to inside of this function and how you might call it.

Comment: I am making a driver which holds many APIs(having different number of params and data types) and they all are calling a single API and passing parameters in it, so I want to know in this API, about the parameters type and want to perform some action

Comment: Maybe include some sample code of what you are trying to achieve. However, @dbush is correct, this isn't possible in C without additional information.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible. The kernel is effectively assembly. If you get a `PVOID`, that's either a 32 or 64 bits address, and you don't even know the size of the object that it points to.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your function like this:

```
void myapi(void *param, enum type param_type);
```

And the associated enum:

```
enum type {
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_CHAR,
    // more types
 };
```

With a body like this:

```
void myapi(void *param, enum type param_type)
{
    if (param_type == TYPE_INT) {
        int *intptr = param;
        // do something with intptr
    } else if (param_type == TYPE_CHAR) {
        char *charptr = param;
        // do something with charptr
    // cases for other types
    }
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
int myint = 0;
myapi(&myint, TYPE_INT);
char mychar = 'x';
myapi(&mychar, TYPE_CHAR);
```

Comment: Yup this strategy could be applicable and i appreciate your effort. but the problem is the APIs are coming from another driver and after applying hook in them, i am getting them into my driver so thats why i don't know the data type, so i need to type cast them accordingly..

Comment: @abdullahtoqeer if the calling function doesn’t give you any information about the data type then there’s no way to know what it might be.   You just have a pointer to some unknown memory block.

Comment: No! calling API just passing the parameters and giving no other information, we need to typecast them accordingly.

Comment: @abdullahtoqeer How do you intend to cast to the correct type if you don't know what the correct type is?  There's nothing in a given block of memory that says it is an `int`, `char`, `double`, or an instance of a `struct`.  Perhaps a more concrete example would help.